# How to return false where the result of JDBC is empty

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In my code, i need when the result of query is empty, it should return `false`.

My code:

```
public boolean user_bookValidationQuery(String userID, String bookID) {
    Connection con;    
    PreparedStatement ps;    
    String query = " select * from borrowed where userID=? and bookID=? ";    
    try {    
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);    
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);    
        ps.setString(1, userID);    
        ps.setString(2, bookID);
        if (ps.execute()) {
            System.out.println("You can do it! , id DB");
            return true;
        } else return false;

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now for a give value for `userID` and `bookID` , i try in mysql console and see that it's result was empty, But in my code it return `true` still!

Why not false here?

Comment: What does the javadoc for PreparedStatement.execute() say about return values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151772/why-does-execute-return-true-on-an-empty-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to check the result of the statement ...

```
ResultSet rs= ps.execute();
rs.isBeforeFirst()
```

will returns false if there are no rows in the ResultSet

so your code should look like this :

```
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, userID);
    ps.setString(2, bookID);
    ResultSet rs= ps.execute();

    if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
          System.out.println("empty"); 
          return false;
    }else {
          System.out.println("with data"); 
          return true;
    }

} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    sqle.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Given that `isBeforeFirst()` is optional for `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` resultsets, it is not the best way to check. Simply checking if the first call to `next()` returns true is the only guaranteed way to check if there is a result.

Comment: Or just `return rs.isBeforeFirst()`. OP should use `executeQuery()`, not `execute()`.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29) doesn't mean what you think it means:

> Returns:
>      `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if the first result is an update count or there is no result

A `SELECT` statement will always produce a `ResultSet` (even if there is no row in the result). Instead you should

1. Use the `ResultSet` obtained from [`executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29)
2. Check the value of [`ResultSet.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) to see if there was **at least** one result

Answer (score 2):

> Why not false here?

According to the javadoc for [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29):

> Returns: `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if the first result is an update count or there is no result.

In your case, the first result will be a `ResultSet` object.  An empty `ResultSet` is still a `ResultSet`.

---

In this case (e.g. when the SQL is a "select") the solution is to use `executeQuery` and test if the `ResultSet` is empty.

Alternatively (e.g. when the SQL *may or may not* return a `ResultSet`), you could test the result of `query()`, and then call `getResultSet()` and test if it is empty.

The most general way to test if a `ResultSet` is empty is to call `next()` on it<sup>1</sup>.  Apparently `ResultSet.isBeforeFirst()` is an optional operation for `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` resultsets.

---

<sup>1 - Of course that `next()` call will advance to the first row in the resultset as per the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Empty result doesn't mean that the SQL exception has occured. You need to check if the result is empty and THEN return false.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong conditional statement even if the result is empty the query will execute and `ps.execute()` will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

javadoc for execute : true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if the first result is an update count or there is no result

Thus whether or not you expect result,for a select statement, execute() would always return true ;

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check ResultSet returned from `execute()` is empty

```
if ( resultSet.next() == false )
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a sample, similar to what Mark Rotteveel above mentioned. I using rs.isBeforeFirst() instead of rs.next() because this way I don't need to reset the current position back to the begining:

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    isLoggedIn = rs.isBeforeFirst();
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work, because `isBeforeFirst()` is optional for forward-only result sets.